# A Problem with saving data to .txt file in c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a program where a user can input data using case 1 and save it to .txt file. But whenever I look to the output using case 2, the first and second data will start with number 1.

The program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

struct bahanbakar{ 
    string nobbm;
    string nama;
    string stok, harga;
};

int menu();
void TampilData(fstream &MyFile, int size);
void IsiData (fstream &MyFile, bahanbakar ListBBM,int size);
void CheckData(fstream &MyFile);
void HitungData(fstream &MyFile, int *size);
void InputData(fstream &MyFile, int size);


main()
{   
    fstream MyFile;

    char lanjut;

    CheckData(MyFile);
    getch();
    int pilih = menu();

    while (pilih!=5)
    {
        int size = 1;
        HitungData(MyFile, &size);
        system("cls");

        switch(pilih)
        {
            case 1: InputData(MyFile,size); break;
            case 2: TampilData(MyFile, size); break;
            case 3: break;
            case 4: break;
            case 5: break;
        }
        MyFile.close();

        cout<<"Kembali ke Menu Awal?(y/n): ";
        cin>>lanjut;

        if(lanjut == 'y' || lanjut == 'Y')
        pilih = menu();

        else break;
    }
}

int menu()
{
    system("cls");
    int pilih;
    cout<<"==============================\n";
    cout<<"==============================\n";

        cout<<"1. INPUT DATA"<<endl;
        cout<<"2. TAMPILKAN DATA"<<endl;
        cout<<"3. SEARCHING DATA"<<endl;
        cout<<"4. SORTING DATA"<<endl;
        cout<<"5. KELUAR"<<endl;

    cout<<"===============================\n";
    cout<<"Masukkan pilihan[1-5]: ";
    cin>>pilih;
    cin.ignore();

    return pilih;

}

void IsiData(fstream &MyFile, bahanbakar ListBBM, int size)
{   
    getline(MyFile,ListBBM.nama);
    getline(MyFile,ListBBM.stok);
    getline(MyFile,ListBBM.harga);
    getline(MyFile,ListBBM.nobbm);

    cout<<"No.BBM   : "<<ListBBM.nobbm;cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Nama BBM: "<<ListBBM.nama;cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Stok : "<<ListBBM.stok;cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Harga    : "<<ListBBM.harga;cout<<endl<<endl;

    if (size>1) IsiData(MyFile, ListBBM, size-1);
}

void TampilData(fstream &MyFile, int size)
{
    bahanbakar ListBBM;

    MyFile.open("ListBBM.txt", ios::in | ios::out);

    cout<<"Daftar BBM: "<<endl;
    IsiData(MyFile,ListBBM,size);

}

void CheckData(fstream &MyFile)
{
    MyFile.open("ListBBM.txt",ios::out|ios::in);

        if (MyFile.is_open())
        {
            cout<<"Data Ada(Klik Enter untuk Melanjutkan)";
            MyFile.close();
        }

        else
        {
            cout<<"File Tidak Ada, File akan dibuat(Klik Enter untuk melanjutkan)";
            MyFile.close();

            MyFile.open("ListBBM.txt",ios::trunc|ios::in|ios::out);
            MyFile.close();
        }

}


void HitungData(fstream &MyFile, int *size)
{
    int temp;

    string wadah, tempat;

    MyFile.open("ListBBM.txt",ios::out|ios::in);

    do
    {
        temp = *size;
        tempat = wadah;

        for(int j=0; j<5;j++)
        {
            getline(MyFile,wadah);
        }

        if (wadah != tempat)
        {
            *size=*size+1;
        }
    }

    while (*size != temp);

    MyFile.close();

    if(*size>0)
    *size=*size-1;
}

void InputData(fstream &MyFile,int size)
{
    bahanbakar ListBBM;

    MyFile.open("ListBBM.txt",ios::app);

    cout << "===================================" << endl;
    cout << "|           TAMBAH BBM          |" << endl;
    cout << "+---------------------------------+" << endl;
    cout << "| Jumlah BBM saat ini : " << setw(3) << size;
    cout << "     |" << endl;
    cout << "===================================" << endl;
    // meminta inputan user
    cout << "-> Nama : ";
    getline(cin,ListBBM.nama);
    cout << "-> Stok : ";
    getline(cin,ListBBM.stok);
    cout << "-> Harga : ";
    getline(cin,ListBBM.harga);
    cout << "===================================" << endl;

    // memindahkan data dari struct ke file
    MyFile << ListBBM.nama << endl;
    MyFile << ListBBM.stok << endl;
    MyFile << ListBBM.harga << endl;
    MyFile << size+1 << endl;

    MyFile.close(); // tutup data
}
```

The output in case 2:

```
Daftar BBM:
No.BBM  : 1
Nama BBM: Oil
Stok    : 10
Harga   : 10000

No.BBM  : 1
Nama BBM: Gasoline
Stok    : 50
Harga   : 7000

No.BBM  : 3
Nama BBM: Water
Stok    : 100
Harga   : 5000

Kembali ke Menu Awal?(y/n):
```

Can someone tell me where I went wrong?

Comment: What does the data look like in the file? That's the first question.

Comment: Side note: don't pass the file stream in if you are going to open and close it in the function. Create a new stream in the function. This reduces inter-dependencies between the functions. Currently one function could leave the stream in a bad or unexpected state and needlessly cause another function to fail.

Comment: Side note: ALWAYS check the state of a stream after an IO transaction. Not checking leaves you wide open to undetected errors.

Answer (score 1):

Look like I already found my mistake, it was in

```
    for(int j=0; j<5;j++)
    {
        getline(MyFile,wadah);
    }
```

I should put j<5 with the number of my variable I'm using so it should be

```
    for(int j=0; j<4;j++)
    {
        getline(MyFile,wadah);
    }
```